# Ubuntu 12.04 production server upgrade

Tags: apt

On a Ubuntu 12.04 webserver we´re sending a nigthly report about upgrades for this machine running a cron with upgrade in dry run

```
apt-get update && upgrade --dry-run
```

In past we created a snapshot and after that run all of the upgrades. A bit worried that an upgrade could break something we´re now thinking about not upgrading every package apt-get tells us. This brings confusion which is the best way to go.

Questions:

1. it common to upgrade every package apt-get tells us? - or only to defined packages

   **apt-get install --only-upgrade packagename**

   If we only upgrade defined packages will apt-get still care about
   dependencies?
2. If it´s adviseable to not run every available upgrade for this
   machine is it better to run only defined upgrades as written above
   or to hold back packages with:

   **apt-mark hold package_name**
3. If none of them is best practise (define or hold packages) is it
   adviseable to check for security upgrades only with

   **apt-get -s dist-upgrade |grep "^Inst" |grep -i securi**

   and run them with

   **apt-get -s dist-upgrade | grep "^Inst" | grep -i securi | awk -F " " {'print $2'} | xargs apt-get install**

Comment: It is generally advisable to regression test upgrades in a lab environment before pushing them to production.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is common to update everything. Do you know how messy administration is going to be if you are holding back random packages across your environment?

The solution is to perform all your upgrades in a staging environment and test everything to make sure everything still works before rolling to prod.

Comment: ok thanks and point 3 (security upgrades only) is also not a good practice?

Comment: Hi Peter, once again me. Yes performing upgrades before this on a staging server makes sense, but do really bigger companies have the time and money to run everything on an identic server? Thats why I asked if there is a best practise to not upgrade everything but security.

Comment: @tBook i guess if you had to choose few to install, it would be best to install the security ones first. If you don't have the time or finances to have a staging env, then you can do whatever you like, I guess (yes, you can update packages on a per-package basis). Going to be very tricky if you ever need to do a distro upgrade.